# OpenShift CLI login issue

Tags: command-line-interface, openshift

I setup an account on OpenShift V3 and now I'm trying to connect with **oc** CLI. I'm using the same credentials as for the web console, but can not login, getting the following error message:

```
> oc login
Authentication required for https://api.starter-us-east-1.openshift.com:443 (openshift)
Username: my_login
Password:
error: The server was unable to respond - verify you have provided the correct host and port and that the server is currently running.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you don't specify a login destination.
After creating a project (e.g. Node.js), OpenShift provides the connection credentials you have to use in order to login.

Basically, it is your API's host at OpenShift.

For instance:

```
oc login https://api.starter-us-west-2.openshift.com
```

---

P.S. You can find the correct login URL in `Builds` → `%YOUR_BUILD%` → `Configuration`, under `Triggers` → `Generic Webhook URL` or `GitHub Webhook URL`.

Comment: Thanks. By default, the oc CLI fetches the wrong API host. Need to look for the proper one in Overview -> Networking

Comment: If you select on the question mark drop down menu from the web console and select 'Command line tools' it will tell you the command to login from the command line using a token. That is the official way of finding out, not digging around in the build configuration. Go try out the 'Logging into an OpenShift cluster' tutorial at https://learn.openshift.com/ as it explains different ways of logging in.

Comment: I would recommend using the answer above rather than the token method shown in the web console. Using the token from the web console will log you out of the CLI when you end your web console session, while using oc login with username/password as shown will create a new token saved on your local machine for the CLI session.

Comment: Using the token based method should not log you out when you end your web console session. The token based method is subject though to token expiration policy in place, which is usually 24 hours. That is 24 hours from when token created initially, not the last time you got the command from the web console. The exception to that is if you go to a specific page to request a new token be created. Even the web console session, or ``oc login`` from command line with passwd has an expiration on it and will be logged out after 24 hours.

Comment: Seeing some more information about this, how expiration works apparently depends for OpenShift Online at least, whether you are on Starter or Pro tier. Tokens in Starter expire in a time frame much longer than 24 hours. In Pro though they expire after 24 hours. Also you are correct that explicitly logging out of the web console can expire the token immediately. Things in Pro tier may not be working as expected right now due to a configuration issue, which is being looked at. I will do some more checking and provide a later update.

Comment: One thing need to look at is whether you go to ``/oauth/token/request`` sub URL of web console and down bottom request a new token, how expiry of that relates to the web console login session.

Answer (score 0):

`oc login YOUR_URL -u USER -p ADMIN` This cmd may help.

Comment: and how can i get my_URL? please answer completely. is it necessary to create my docker before?

Comment: You are supposed to have a openshit cluster at the first hand